# Where to view error log for already finished tar archive command?

Tags: logs, tar

I ran below command:

```
tar cvf ~/data.tar /home/user/data/
```

It showed lot of filenames on the screen, after 10 minutes I see:

> tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Where can I see the error log for tar (is it somewhere under `/var/log`). I can see that there is 100 Mb difference between the tarred version and the original. I want to know the names of missing files from newly created archive.

```
du -sh data.tar /home/user/data
5.7G     data.tar
5.8G      /home/user/data
```

Using GNU tar 1.27.1

Comment: The question is useful, but if it's a backup, I would advise restarting the operation from scratch. Some files could be in the archive already, but corrupted because `tar` exited while writing them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`tar` is an interactive command, not a service and does not produce log files.

Its output is sent to `stdout` and errors to `stderr`.

You can redirect the output streams to files, but you would need to run it again.

```
tar cvf ~/data.tar /home/user/data/ > tar_stdout.log 2> tar_stderr.log
```

And examine the contents of the file `tar_stderr.kog`.

Or combine both streams into one file:

```
tar cvf ~/data.tar /home/user/data/ &> tar.log
```

Answer (score 6):

Since your tar was pretty large you may not want to repeat it and collect the errors as in the other answers, so do a sort of dummy version to `/dev/null` dropping the `v` option and keeping the errors:

```
tar cf /dev/null /home/user/data/ 2>errors
```

Comment: I tried this, `errors` contains `tar: Removing leading / from member names ` No other error.

Comment: Running the real command again showed additional errors, such as Permission denied errors.

Comment: That's bad luck. Must be an OS difference. Works for me with gnu tar 1.28. (tar --version). Eg on /tmp I get errors like `tar: /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: socket ignored`, and `tar: /tmp/nspawn-root-9rooX8: Cannot open: Permission denied`.

Comment: You can avoid some of the i/o overhead by piping the tar output to `/dev/null`. It's not as fast since it still has to read all the data, but at least you dont write it all again: `tar cf - /home/user/data/ 2>errors | cat >/dev/null`

Answer (score 3):

You would have to capture the log while you are untarring the file, e.g.,

```
tar cvf ~/data.tar /home/user/data/ 2>tar.errors |tee tar.output
```

to put the errors in `tar.errors`, watch the normal output, and put *that* in `tar.output`.